# a variadic template as a template parameter without pack expansion

Tags: c++14, variadic-templates

I found that the following code compiles and runs successfully with VS 2015:

```
template<typename T, template <typename ...> class Container >
struct Holder
{
    Container<T> container_;
};

int main()
{
    Holder<int, std::vector> h;
    h.container_.push_back(10);
    std::cout << h.container_.at(0);
}
```

Could you please tell me whether this way follows the standard to specify a template-template parameter without listing parameter types (type of the container elements and allocator type in the above example)?

Comment: What does it mean _whether this way follows the standard_? It is allowed, that's all. Do you want to know if the standard template library does something similar somewhere? The question is pretty unclear.

Comment: Thanks, I want to know if it's allowed to use variadic template that way (or it's some MS C++ non-stadard feature).

Comment: As long as the `Container` does not have any non-type template parameters, it will work and it is standard conformant (I'm using it with GCC and Clang for several years now). Only older versions of some compilers fail, but this is a bug in those compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if it's allowed to use variadic template that way (or it's some MS C++ non-stadard feature)

According with the [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.template) (working draft, but the same applies to C++11/C++14), it's perfectly valid code. The standard contains also a few examples of use like the following one:

```
template <class T> struct eval;

template <template <class, class...> class TT, class T1, class... Rest>
struct eval<TT<T1, Rest...>> { };
```

You need a parameter pack for the container because several of the ones defined in the standard template library accept more than one argument (even though almost all of those parameters have a default value).
As an example, the container used in your your code is declared as:

```
template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>> class vector;
```

Therefore, the following wouldn't have been matched:

```
template<typename T, template <typename> class Container> struct Holder;
```